# Compute $E(X)$ if $F_X(x)=e^{-\lambda x^{-\delta}}$

Tags: probability, expectation

I am trying to calculate the expected value for this cdf:

$F_X(x)=e^{-\lambda x^{-\delta}}   ,   x \ge 0, \lambda >0 ,\delta >0.$

which gives the pdf as:

$f_X(x) = \lambda \delta x^{\delta -1} e^{-\lambda x^{-\delta}}$

I am trying to calculate the expectation using:

$E\{x\} = \int_0^ \infty \lambda \delta x^{\delta} e^{-\lambda x^{-\delta}} dx $

but the calculation of above expectation gives me infinity as expected value!I am confused wether I am wrong in calculation or there is any trick to get rid of infinity or the infinity makes sense as the expectation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x^{-\delta-1}$?

Comment: By definition, $$E(X) = \int_0^ \infty \lambda \delta x^{-\delta} e^{-\lambda x^{-\delta}} dx $$
The change of variable $$u=\lambda x^{-\delta}$$ yields $$x=\lambda^{1/\delta}u^{-1/\delta}\qquad du=\lambda \delta x^{-\delta-1}dx$$
hence $$E(X) = \int_0^ \infty  \lambda^{1/\delta}u^{-1/\delta}e^{-u} du=\lambda^{1/\delta}\Gamma(1-1/\delta) $$

Comment: @Did *Bis repetita placent*?

Comment: @ClementC. ...sed perseverare diabolicum est. :-) Don't know what happened but indeed, once is quite enough.

Comment: Thanks @Did, but what about the values of $\delta$ , for which the value of gamma function is negative? because the expectation of a positive random variable cant be negative, right?

Comment: If $\delta\leqslant1$ then $E(X)$ is infinite hence $E(X)=\lambda^{1/\delta}\Gamma(1-1/\delta)$ if $\delta>1$ and $E(X)=\infty$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your chosen parametrization,
$$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}[X] &= \int_{x=0}^\infty x f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty \lambda \delta x^{-\delta} \exp(-\lambda x^{-\delta}) \, dx, \quad u = \lambda x^{-\delta}, \quad du = -\lambda \delta x^{-\delta - 1} \, dx, \quad x = (u/\lambda)^{-1/\delta},\\
&= \int_{u=0}^\infty (u/\lambda)^{-1/\delta} e^{-u} \, du \\
&= \lambda^{1/\delta} \int_{u=0}^\infty u^{(1 - 1/\delta) - 1} e^{-u} \, du \\
&= \lambda^{1/\delta} \Gamma(1 - 1/\delta),
\end{align*}$$
where we have used the definition of the gamma function $$\Gamma(z) = \int_{t=0}^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t} \, dt.$$  Indeed, it is easy to see that the $k^{\rm th}$ raw moment under your parametrization is $$\operatorname{E}[X^k] = \lambda^{k/\lambda} \Gamma(1-k/\lambda).$$

Comment: thank you @heropup, and sorry for my mistake, but using gamma function, suggests that for say, $\delta=0.28$ the expectation of a positive random variable is negative!! Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in the sign of the derivative! A $-$ sign should precede $\delta$ in the power of $x$

Comment: The question asked "wether I am wrong in calculation or there is any trick to get rid of infinity or the infinity?", and the answer is indeed "yes; your calculation yields an infinity because you had dropped a negative sign in an exponent."  Although, I suppose it could have been expanded a bit more.